# I am trying to execute the following query, but it always reports an error

Tags: sql, postgresql

Schema

```
Tenants (HouseID, ApartmentNumber, LeaseTenantSSN, LeaseStartDate(not null), LeaseExpirationDate(can be null),
 Rent, LastRentPaidDate, RentOverdue)
NewRentPayments (HouseID, ApartmentNumber, LeaseTenantSSN(not null), Rent(can be null), DatePaid)
```

Query

```
INSERT INTO Tenants (x.HouseID,x.ApartmentNumber,x.LeaseTenantSSN,CURRENT_DATE,NULL,x.Rent,x.Rent,FALSE)
SELECT  x.HouseID, x.ApartmentNumber,x.LeaseTenantSSN,CURRENT_DATE,NULL,x.Rent,x.Rent                  
FROM NewRentPayments x
WHERE x.HouseID NOT IN (select HouseID
                FROM Tenants)
      OR x.ApartmentNumber NOT IN (SELECT ApartmentNumber
                   FROM Tenants
                   WHERE Tenants.HouseID=x.HouseID);
```

I always get an error on CURRENT_DATE,NULL.It says sintax error at or near CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  Following `INSERT INTO` should be a list of column names into which you plan on inserting data, using the following `SELECT` as the source.  Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO Tenants (HouseID, ApartmentNumber, LeaseTenantSSN, LeaseStartDate,
                     LeaseExpirationDate, Rent, LastRentPaidDate, RentOverdue)
SELECT x.HouseID, x.ApartmentNumber, x.LeaseTenantSSN, CURRENT_DATE, NULL, x.Rent,
       x.DatePaid, FALSE
FROM NewRentPayments x
WHERE x.HouseID NOT IN (SELECT HouseID FROM Tenants) OR
      x.ApartmentNumber NOT IN (SELECT ApartmentNumber FROM Tenants
                                WHERE Tenants.HouseID=x.HouseID);
```

I selected `FALSE` for the `RentOverdue` value, which seems to agree with your logic.

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO` requires the name of the columns in the which the given data must be inserted, after the table name. Obviously, `CURRENT_DATE` and `NULL` are not the name of the columns.